# Using Docker/Fig with StrongLoop

Tags: strongloop

I'm having a problem using Docker/Fig to set up StrongLoop.

'slc run' works locally but it runs into an error when I run 'fig up'

I have a very basic fig file:

```
web:
  build: .
  command: slc run
  volumes:
    - .:/srv/data
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - mysql
mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:xxx
```

Edit: This is my Dockerfile

```
# Pull nodejs base image
FROM google/nodejs:0.10.30

RUN apt-get -y update

# Install stongloops
RUN npm install --global pg strongloop

#Get source code
RUN cd / && git clone https://github.com/dmathewwws/ios-api.git

# Install dependencies
RUN cd /ios-api && npm install

# Expose running port
EXPOSE 3000

WORKDIR /ios-api
```

This is the error returned:

```
Creating iosapi_mysql_1...

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/bin/fig", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('fig==1.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'fig')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fig/cli/main.py", line 31, in main
command.sys_dispatch()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fig/cli/docopt_command.py", line 21, in sys_dispatch
self.dispatch(sys.argv[1:], None)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fig/cli/command.py", line 28, in dispatch
super(Command, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fig/cli/docopt_command.py", line 24, in dispatch
self.perform_command(*self.parse(argv, global_options))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fig/cli/command.py", line 56, in perform_command
handler(project, command_options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fig/cli/main.py", line 427, in up
insecure_registry=insecure_registry,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fig/project.py", line 174, in up
for (_, container) in service.recreate_containers(insecure_registry=insecure_registry):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fig/service.py", line 199, in recreate_containers
container = self.create_container(insecure_registry=insecure_registry, **override_options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fig/service.py", line 176, in create_container
container_options = self._get_container_create_options(override_options, one_off=one_off)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fig/service.py", line 371, in _get_container_create_options
container_options['environment'] = dict(resolve_env(k, v) for k, v in container_options['environment'].iteritems())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Comment: What is in your Dockerfile?

Comment: @RyanGraham sounds like its possible, I was thinking maybe it was a problem that the 'mysql' container wasn't set up by time 'web' container was trying to connect to it.

Comment: You should also include what the error message you got was... otherwise it's pretty much impossible to know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have copy/pasted your `fig.yml` accurately, it has an error in it.

To use the dictionary format for the environment variables, you need a space between `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:` and `xxx`.

```
mysql:
  image: mysql:latest
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxx
```

Alternatively you can use the array form, which is a list of strings of the form `VAR=val`:

```
mysql:
  image: mysql:latest
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxx
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I also changed the 'host' in the datasources.json for my mysql to be the boot2docker ip. Both these changes fixed the issue.